# magento how to display different image banners for sub categories

Tags: magento, categories, banner

I need different images "banners" for all of my sub category pages. Currently they are inheriting the image of the category they are a sub of.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: A few questions.  1. On your subcategories is `Is Anchor` set to `Yes` on the `Display Settings` tab?  2. Are you assigning unique images to your subcategories?  3. Is `Use Parent Category Settings` set to `No` on the `Custom Design` tab?

Comment: is anchor is set to yes, yes we are assigning unique images to sub cats, use parent categories is set to no

Comment: i also noticed that for some reason it works when it is the first sub category but not a sub of a sub, ie   shirt>long sleeves works but shirts>long sleeve>v-neck doesn't it will display long sleeve image not v-neck even though the image is loaded on v'neck

Comment: Make sure `v'neck` is set `Is Anchor` to `Yes` also.  It could also be related a custom theme.  Try setting the default Magento theme temporarily and seeing if you get the same results.

Comment: it is set to anchor and I tried changing the theme to default and it still displays the parent sub cat image banner.

Comment: I think I figured out what the issue is. When I thought I was choosing the sub-cat I am actually using the narrow by list, so instead of bringing me to the page V-neck itself it is bringing me to shirt?cat=23 Any suggestions on how display shirts>vnecks instead of shirt?cat=23

Comment: It only filters like that based on your category anchor settings.  Double check that all categories in the category tree are set to anchors.  Other than that, I have no idea.  It could be an underlying issue somewhere else.  Also make sure you're flushing your MAgento cache after making these changes.

Comment: any idea of how to move the category navigation about the layered navigation on the left side?

Comment: There's plenty of Magento documentation outlining how to sort the order of your layout blocks.

Comment: so i have the cat-navigation above the layered navigation using a before and after, but originally the layered navigation was set to after"currency" after i make my change currency is at the bottom even though i set catalog.topnav to after="currency". I can't find the currency value any where else in the xml or any others for that matter. any suggestions? is there a way to move the currency underneath the search box instead of in the left nav?

Comment: i found an article about moving it to the header, http://www.pauldonnelly.net/magento-move-currency-switcher-to-the-header/    when doing this, it still has currency dropdown on the left nav as well. Or if i try to add it to catalog.xml to include a before="" it has two in the left nav

Comment: The comments section really isn't the place for extended discussions about off-topic questions.  I suggest either creating a new question detailing the question you have (only after doing your own research), or going the Magento Chat and asking these questions there: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28702/magento-experts